# Keyboard layout persisting after disk erasure/OS reinstall

Tags: keyboard, disk-format

Today I erased Macintosh HD and re-installed the OS (Catalina 10.15.7) in an attempt to start *everything* from scratch on my Macbook Air (Early 2014, pls don't judge me haha).

One of first things to do once the re-install was over was add a custom keyboard layout that I used to have and had backed up. I AirDropped the `.bundle` file and placed it in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts`, then opened up Keyboard Preferences, navigated to *Others*, and there were **two of the same input source**.

I headed back to `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts`, removed the `.bundle` file, restared the laptop, then re-launched Keyboard Preferences and the custom input source was still there, only this time there was only just one.

It's really strange how a keyboard layout could have persisted a disk erasure + OS reinstall. Any ideas why this is happening or where the persistent keylayout file could be? This is making me a little bit paranoid tbh.

Solution: I was able to get rid of the phantom keylayout this way:

1. remove the keylayout bundle from `/Library/Keyboard Layouts`
2. add it to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` (without the tilde)
3. remove  the bundle you just added to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts`
4. restart the laptop.

It still doubles up when I add it to the keylayouts folder, so apparently it didn't have anything to do with the OS reinstall or a file persisting, it's just some weird behaviour of the system (which I didn't experience however previously).

If you want to add the keylayout after all, add it to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` (without the tilde), then a simple restart should solve the doubling up.

Comment: Why do you think it persisted the reinstall? Seems to be the custom layout showing up, from looking at the steps you took.

Comment: @nohillside because it didn't go away the 'Others' when I deleted the newly-added `.bundle` from `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts`. It's still there even though `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts` and `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` are totally empty.

Comment: Does this phantom keyboard actually work?  Try doing a safeboot to eliminate cache issues.   https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac

Comment: @TomGewecke, yep, it's working like a charm. Did the safeboot, doesn't seem to help. Also cleared NVRAM, didn't help either.

Comment: Looks like it didn't have to do anything with a file persisting, please see the update.

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question. Separate it out to be an actual answer. Then you can accept it yourself as 'most helpful' & the stack exchange karma bunnies are happy :))